# how to use @property in Django models? how to get the details of company models and futsalusers in to single table?

Tags: django

```
class FutsalUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )

    objects = FutsalUserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def company_details(self):
       company_data =  Company.objects.filter(user= self)
       if company_data :
           company_data.name
           return company_data
       else:
           return None




class Company(TimeStampedModel):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    hr_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    hr_email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.DO_NOTHING)
    hr_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    primary_phone = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)
    followed_by = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="Not assigned")
    comments = models.TextField(default="")

   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: You can access ``company_details`` it like this ``FutsalUser.company_details()``

Comment: def subject_fee(request):
   s = Registration.company_details.object.all()
   context = {'s':s}
   return render(request,'fee.html',context)     

is this correct?

Comment: Hello @dilja no it's not it should be ``FutsalUser.company_details()``

Comment: ok , how to write the view function ?

Comment: def futsal_details(request):
   s = FUTSALUSER.company_details()

   context = {'s':s}
   return render(request,'fee.html',context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** There is no need to create a custom function in Model, to fetch other values of other table which are in relation.

[ 1 ] you should have a `related_name` in your company user table. like

```
user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='company')
# you can name company with something of your own choice.

# following will be more appropriate. 
user = models.ForeignKey(
        FutsalUser, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='company')
```

[ 2 ] once you have a related_name, you can fetch the companies values as following.

```
FutsalUser.objects.all().values('email', 'is_active', 'company__name', 'company__hr_email')
```

**2.** Apart from that you can fetch the details from `Company` table instead.

```
Company.objects.all().values('name', 'user__email') # you can add more field if you want.
```

**3**

```
users = FatalUser.objects.all()
for user in users:
    company_list = user.company_details
    # this company_list will have the companies associated with user. 
    print(company_list)
    for company in company_list:
        print(company.name, company.hr_email)
```

Comment: but in this case , company table doent have all the futsalusers so , when i call the like  Company.objects.all().values('name', 'user__email')  , it given the values only related to company object

Comment: Your company don't have FutSalUsers anyway, it has ```settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL```(not sure, why it is there). anyway your function is having data from table only, is the ```None``` part you are worry about?

Comment: Actually this is not an internal database platform and it is a live one too, so I can't touch the database. now AUTH_USER_MODEL is changed as FUTSALUSERS_MODEL.  The problem is all the users in the FUTSALUSERS may not have name in COMPANY MODEL but I need all users in FUTSALUSERS and if they have name in COMPANY, that too.  So I added a property in FUTSALUSERS. Can you plz tell how to write a view function for it??

Comment: No. even if there is a way to do that. I don't want to look into that and make it complex just for the sake of it.
a simple and straight flow would taking all the required users and passing them into Company. you ll get the company name or anything what you want, in the end it is details that you want. if you want I can edit my code for my that purpose.

Comment: unfortunately I  must  do in that way only  can you please help with that code ? to write my view function?

Comment: how can I call the property function in to my views?

Comment: @dilja I have edited the code. now you can do anything with that ```company``` (store that in a dict, list however you like)

Comment: 'QuerySet' object is not callable it showing the error like this , company = user.company_details() in this line

Comment: @dilja I have edited the code, I can't reporoduce your code in my system. so I had to manually write that, sorry for trouble. now you ll get list of compnies associated with that user. after that you can loop over companies_list to get the individual company. ```for company in compnay_list```. I hope you would be able to do that yourself(let me know)

Comment: Thank you for your support , but unfortunately  I getting the values of company models only , I didn't  get the values of FUTSALUSER ,''' for company in company_list:
        print( company.email)'''' its not getting , I just want to get all the details of FUTSALUSER model and related details of COMPANY like left join  , for that  I just add the property  . I don't know whether the property is right or not ,  could you please help me to fix it ?